# DB::select procedure return empty array from input request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created this function in my controller:

```
public function productInvoiceListTest(Request $request){
    $var = $request->client_id;
    $date = "2019-12-30";

    $sql = 'CALL proc_invoice_product_list("'.$var.'","i.invoice_date","2019-12-30","","")';

    $productinvoice = DB::select($sql);
    var_dump($productinvoice);
}
```

When i run the code its return empty array, but when i hardcode value of `$var` it works:

```
public function productInvoiceListTest(Request $request){
    $var = 'dasdsdasdsadsadsa';
    $date = "2019-12-30";

    $sql = 'CALL proc_invoice_product_list("'.$var.'","i.invoice_date","2019-12-30","","")';

    $productinvoice = DB::select($sql);
    var_dump($productinvoice);
}
```

Why when i use input from request can't call my procedure? How do i read from input request?

Comment: Maybe you can try `$var = $request->input('client_id');`

Comment: how do you access request input ?

Comment: using `$request->input('client_id');` it doesn't work too,,

Comment: I access using `$request->client_id`, I have tried echo value of `$request->client_id` it's return as expect but using inside `CALL ...` doesn't work

Comment: `$var = $request->client_id` isinya apa bro @AepSaepudin?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first confirm the client_id is being passed to your **productInvoiceListTest** method by using the dd helper.

```
public function productInvoiceListTest(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

If the client_id is part of the the request instance passed in your **productInvoiceListTest** method, then you can access it using $request->input('client_id') method. If it is not part of the request instance, ensure that from the method calling or redirecting to **productInvoiceListTest**, the **client_id** is passed.

Comment: `array:2 [
  "client_id" => "QW9a414bc5-1263-11e9-881c-001e67fa8453-ID"
  "date" => "2019-12-30"
]` 

its return normally,,

Comment: Then now try to access client_id by extracting it from the request instance using $var = $request->client_id;

and confirm if you see it, If you do, you then then try using it in your query

Comment: its return normally too,, 
I think laravel have feature that doesn't allow passing direct parameter for security reason maybe,,

Comment: Try:

$sql = DB:raw(
    'call proc_invoice_product_list(?, ?, ?),
    [
        $var,
 i.invoice_date,
 $date),
    ]
);